# Making a ggsurvplot with a coxph

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, propensity-score-matching

I've coded the following `coxph`object

```
cox <- coxph(Surv(INTERVAL, PX_STAT_CODE) ~ TX_NUM, data = outcomes_1and2above, robust = TRUE, weights = weights, cluster=subclass)
```

from a propensity score matched dataset and would like to create a KM plot that delineates by `TX_NUM`. I'm using the following code

```
fit <- survfit(cox, data=outcomes_1and2above)
ggsurvplot(fit, data=outcomes_1and2above)
```

which returns

[image]

I was able to do this previously with the unmatched dataset using the following code

```
outcomes_1and2above_Surv <- Surv(time = outcomes_1and2above$INTERVAL, event = outcomes_1and2above$PX_STAT_CODE)
km_fit_txnum_12a <- survfit(outcomes_1and2above_Surv ~ outcomes_1and2above$TX_NUM, data = outcomes_1and2above)
ggsurvplot(fit = outcomes_1and2above_Surv, data = outcomes_1and2above)
```

but am unable to replicate this with the matched data since the `Surv` function doesn't have a `weights` argument.

Comment: If you did 1:1 matching without replacement, you don't need to include weights in the final analysis. This may be a reason to favor this method in your case.

Comment: This works, but like you've pointed out in previous posts I lose a lot of data (probably 80% of my dataset).  I'd hate to throw out all that data for the sake of a figure.

Comment: `survfit()` accepts a `weights` argument. Does that not work?

Comment: I'm not sure why one would expect the `Surv` function to accept a weights argument. (It's the outcome in a survival analysis.) The regression function would be expected to deal with the weights being applied to covariates.I think a MCVE is needed. ( You should also learn to use a data argument in survfit, not build `Surv` objects outside the regression function calls, and not use `$` in formulae.)